# How do I view the spacy NER softmax values?

Tags: python, spacy, named-entity-recognition, spacy-3

I'm trying to obtain the softmax predictions for each output class from the spacy NER model. When I place a break point at 'preds' in the code below and skip through the pipeline until the predict method is being called on the NER model pipeline component I can see that object returned from the self._func call is a 'ParserStepModel' object.

```
import spacy
from thinc.model import Model, InT, OutT

def predict(self, X:InT) -> OutT:

    preds = self._func(self, X, is_train=False)[0]

    return preds

Model.predict = predict

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

def show_ents(doc):
    if doc.ents:
        for ent in doc.ents:
            print(ent.text + ' - ' + str(ent.start_char) + ' - ' + str(ent.end) + ' - ' +
                  ent.label_ + ' - ' + str(spacy.explain(ent.label_)))
    else:
        print('No named entities found.')

doc = nlp('Apple is looking at buying U.K. startup for $1 billion')

show_ents(doc)
```

I assume that the 'ParserStepModel' object contains the results of processing the input text as I can see the object contains the properties 'tokvec' and the model 'vec2scores'. I was therefore assuming that if were to run the model and the vectorised input i.e.

```
preds.vec2scores(preds.tokvecs, is_train = False)
```

The resulting array would be a softmax prediction for each of the entities. However the outputs don't appear to change if I set is_train = True. I was hoping someone could explain how I can view the softmax predictions from the NER model and which entities the softmax predictions relate to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The NER component uses a transition-based parsing model that doesn't really provide useful scores for individual entity predictions.

If you need meaningful confidence scores for entity predictions, train a [`spancat`](https://spacy.io/api/spancategorizer) component instead of `ner`. The scores are saved under `doc[spans_key].attrs["scores"]`.

Some related threads:

- https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/831
- https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/discussions/9189

Comment: Thanks @aab. Sorry I don't fully understand (I'm still very new to NLP and deep neural networks). I thought the NER uses a deep neural network prediction (the pipeline component has a Thinc model), in which case wouldn't the prediction from the model (as above) give a softmax output? I was hoping to turn on training (dropout) in the prediction to get a Monte Carlo prediction.

Comment: The underlying model provides scores for moves/actions in the transition-based parser rather than for whole entity spans. For an introduction to transition-based parsing, see section 14.4 of Jurafsky and Martin's _Speech and Language Processing_: https://www.web.stanford.edu/~jurafsky/slp3/14.pdf.  For token / span / text labeling, the components `tagger` / `spancat` / `textcat` are more straightforward for this kind of use.