# How do I get confidence score in spacy 3.5 prediction?

Tags: nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition, spacy-3

I am working with spacy 3.5. Everything is great, but did not find a way to get confidence score from my NER prediction.

I trained a custom NER model with spacy 3.5. I am able to make predictions using the model. However there is no way through which I can get confidence scores for my predictions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I view the spacy NER softmax values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72874877/how-do-i-view-the-spacy-ner-softmax-values)

Comment: https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/discussions/13193
How about this answer? You get an array of probabilities and the pipeline search for the bigger value.